# Codename one calendar change selected day style

Tags: java, android, calendar, codenameone

Now I am working with Codename one Calendar API, it is working fine, But I have some design issue with calendar ui.
My requirement is when I am clicking on particular day and add it as an event day, then the color of that day will get change.

**Following is my application screen shot:-**

[image]

Comment: It isn't clear what you want to achieve.  In the screenshot, it shows that the 4th has a different style than the other days, therefore (assuming that the 4th is the selected day) it would seem that you have already achieved what your question states.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to override the `CalendarSelectedDay` UIID and obviously override the styles for selected/pressed/unselected for all applicable UIID's.